# Why does WordPress hide the reset password key from the URL?

Tags: login

I'm currently working on a WordPress plugin of my own that involves a custom login interface. I'm wondering, why is it that when you reset your password on WP-Admin, WordPress stores the reset password key in a cookie rather retrieve it from the URL through `$_GET`?

For example, if your reset link is `https://example.com/wp-admin/?action=rp&key=123123213213213123&login=admin`, the link will store `$_GET['key']` and `$_GET['login']` in a cookie and serve you this page using the cookie: `https://example.com/wp-admin/?action=rp`.

Are there any security reasons for doing that?

Comment: Yes. It's definitely because of security reasons

Comment: Why do you assume there is any answer which is more of a "because"?. Not every line of code has some deep thought behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest? It's a little bit hard to say...

This behavior was introduced in 3.9.2 (which is security release). Here's the bug in Trac: [29060: Don't pass around the resetpass key](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29060), but there isn't much info on why was it introduced in the bug report.

Is it for security reasons? Most probably. But does it really make the process more secure? It's a little bit hard to say...

Both GET params and Cookies are sent in every request - so attacker still can intercept them. It just makes such attempts a little bit harder (since you have to get pass_key and it's hashed value).

Comment: This is a very long way to say "I do not know as well" ;). Upvoted because otherwise the question will keep poping up, while the only place to get an authoritative answer will be to ask nacin himself.

Comment: @MarkKaplun yes and no. There’s a question about that change in the bug report I’ve mentioned. It’s 22 months old now and still has no answer ;) It just makes MiM attacks a little bit harder, I guess... I don’t see any other reason for that in the code...

Comment: I don't know, maybe in 3.9 you had to do it to handle some actual security issue, but further changes in later releases made that change obsolete, and the only reason the code works now like it does is because no one felt like it needs to be changed again. So knowing the reason for the original change, might still not explain why it works like it does in 4.9. BTW I am pretty sure MiM has nothing to do with that, my guess is probably handling brute force attacks against the password reset

Comment: @MarkKaplun I guess using nonces would be the fix for BF attacks. This doesn't solve it - you can easily obtain hashed value from server and it doesn't get changed, so... It's sad that there is no docs for this bug/fix - Nacin just requested that change and that's all info you can find now... So I'm afraid, today, nobody knows/remembers why it is like so ;)

Comment: are you really blaming core in writing a correct code that actually solves correctly the issue? ;). I agree that this change is unlikely by itself to solve any problem (maybe only against very naive attacker). I also looked at CVEs and there is none relating to password resets in 3.9.1 that I could find

Comment: I was commenting here, but it was getting bigger, so posted my own answer instead. I agree with @MarkKaplun, this has nothing to do with MITM. Keeping the `key` in the address bar has a small security issue. The original reason behind the update may be something else as well, but this is what I could think of.

Answer (score 5):

There is a couple of **security** benefits I can think of when you do it this way:

1. If you go to the reset URL from your email, but forget to do the actual reset, someone having the **visual access** to your screen (either directly from behind you or from a security camera in front of you screen) has a higher chance of getting the reset URL from your browser address bar with the value of the `key` attribute. So setting it to Cookie & then redirecting to `https://example.com/wp-login.php?action=rp` helps in that regard.
2. It **keeps the browser history cleaner**. Because of the redirect, **`key` will not show up in the browser history**. For example, you are using a little safer browser setting where Cookie is being cleaned after you close the browser window. With `key` in the browser URL, history may still keep it and someone may use it later without you knowing it (in case you've visited the link but didn't use it). So keeping the `key` in the Cookie & then redirecting helps in this case as well.

Granted, this is not the most extraordinary security enhancement, however, it's still an improvement (even if these are the only benefits you get from this update).

> **Note:** I don't think this has any serious security benefit like fending off MITM attacks. MITM is same for `GET` & `Cookie`. Using `HTTPS` solves both.

Comment: 1. Isn’t exactly true - it’s in the email, so it will get recorded ;)

Comment: LOL, yeah. But you can fix that by setting the URL in href ;)

Comment: Well, any client still will show it. And it will be visible in the browser before the redirection happens ;)

Comment: ha ha, for fraction of a second. But it's still an improvement, no?

Comment: if we’re talking about using recorders? That’s not an improvement - it still is visible, so will get recorded. It’s pretty hard to explain now, why that change was made, I guess...

Comment: upvoted for the same reason I upvoted @KrzysiekDróżdż answer, but same reservations I noted in the comments there apply here as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering exactly the same. The best explanation I was able to find was here:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/is-your-site-leaking-password-reset-links

If a user clicks the password reset link from an email and the full url is left in the browser, if they don't reset their password and click an out link on the password reset page, the full password reset link will be shared in the HTTP referer.

Admittedly, Wordpress does not have any out links on wp-login.php, but a lot of people customise this page and it's relatively easy to see the possible security concern.